# iOS 6 Native UI Elements

Tags: xcode4, ios6

Does iOS 6 provide a way for developers to copy its user interface, i.e. if I want my app to look like iTunes or the App Store, can I easily do that using the SDK or do I have to design that on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you implement this. If you take a loot at the file system, you will see that the UI is actually images that Apple uses. You will have to roll your own, but I am sure sooner or later there will be similar images for you to use on the internet. You can then use UIAppearance proxy to set the look and feel to be as similar to Apple's as possible.